# How to select a range of a predefined variable

Tags: excel, vba, range

My code is the following:
For example as devisebase I might have EUR
and for deviseconv I might have USD
I already have in the worksheet a predefined range named EURUSD and I want to be able to retrieve information from this range.

So for example how can I simply retrieve the cell(1,1) for my range EURUSD?

```
  Public Function ccyusd(devisebase As Variant, deviseconv As Variant, taux As Variant, durée As Variant)

Dim range As Variant

range = devisebase & deviseconv

ccyusd = range(range).Cells(1, 1)

End Function
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should not use `range` as a variable name.

Comment: Oh yes, I think it was the issue, thank you!